# Google Cloud Platform - IAM policies inheritance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

In a Google document about IAM policies hierarchy (see below image). it is written that:

- A less restrictive parent policy overrides a more restrictive resource policy

This means to me that if the parent allows edit of below resources, but a single resource policy does not allow edit, the resulting policy is the union, which means that the less restrictive policy (allow to edit) will be the resulting one.

In the same document they provide an example:

- The policies implemented at a higher level in this hierarchy can’t take away access that’s granted at lower level. For example, suppose that a policy applied on the “bookshelf” project gives user Pat the right to modify a Cloud Storage bucket. But a policy at the organization level says that Pat can only view Cloud Storage buckets, not change them. The more generous policy takes effect.

This means to me that if the parent does not allow edit, but the single below resource policy allows edit, the parent still is able to remove edit permission on the resource. Which to me sounds like the less generous policy is taking effect, as an intersection, not a union.
How do you interpret "more generous"? To me, the more generous policy is the one allowing you to do more things, which, in this example, it is granting editing permission, which is the contrary of what it is written.

Does this mean that the less restrictive policy always "wins" since it would be the UNION of the policies?

In other words:

- A less restrictive parent policy overrides a more restrictive resource policy
- A more restrictive parent policy does not override a less restrictive resource policy

Does it make sense to you? thanks

[image: google cloud platform IAM]

Comment: If you reverse the logic, this will make sense. A less restrictive policy means more permissions are granted/allowed. Permissions are inherited down the hierarchy. A more restrictive policy means fewer permissions are granted/allowed. A permission granted at a higher level flows down to lower levels. A permission not granted at a higher level can be granted at a lower level.

Comment: which means that the less restrictive policy 'wins' regardless of where it is granted. which is different than what is written in the document in the yellow part highlighted. you are saying that lower levels cannot remove permissions granted at higher levels, and higher levels cannot remove permissions granted at lower levels. so it does not matter where you grant the permission, once you grant it, nothing can deny it since it would be a more restrictive policy.

Comment: 1) If you ignore **constraints** yes. 2) IAM grants permissions and does not deny (deny is the default). 3) Constraints can prevent permissions from being granted and actions from being performed. https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints 4) I do not feel the documentation is confusing. This is a complex topic that requires a solid understanding of Google Cloud Security. This is not something you will pick from watching a few online courses or links. I spent several years mastering GCP security after spending decades in security.

Answer (score 1):

It only means that all policies are strictly structured top-down, while the more restrictive ones are not necessarily inherited, the rest is (the exception is when there are further policies on lower levels, which may then define what more and less restrictive even means). Else this wouldn't permit that lower levels in the hierarchy could have custom policies.

Comment: lower levels can totally have custom policies and grant permissions that were not granted at higher levels. I think the documentation is confusing and it should just say that you can grant permissions at any level and once a permission is granted, it can't be removed by another policy at a different level.in other words, if your top admin has editing permissions, a random project owner can't decide that admin will not have permissions anymore and apply a stricter policy